# itextsharp goto table next line with a space

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I'm making a very simple report. In which I want maintain same alignments in the whole document.

Problem;

```
 Reference No      :  MP014
 Present Address   :  blah blah ...........................................blah
                    blah...blah......
```

But I want it to be like this.

```
 Reference No      :  MP014
 Present Address   :  blah blah ...........................................blah
                      blah...blah......
```

This is the code I used. Please help me

```
first.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("ID No", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
first.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(": " + id, other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });

 first.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Present Address", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
 first.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(": " + present_address, other)) { BorderWidth = 1 });
```

Comment: Why don't you use a table with three columns? The middle column being the one with the `":"`? Or why don't you add the `":"` in the first colum, aligned to the right using a special "glue" `Chunk`? (There's more than one way to solve this problem.)

Comment: Thanks very much. I was  trapped inside "2 cells" and "tables"

Comment: I'm adding an answer for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by introducing an extra column:

```
Paragraph paragraphTable3 = new Paragraph();
paragraphTable3.SpacingBefore = 20f;
paragraphTable3.SpacingAfter = 10f;

PdfPTable third_table = new PdfPTable(3);
third_table.TotalWidth = 560f;
third_table.LockedWidth = true;
third_table.SetWidths(new float[] { 2.4f,0.1f, 6.6f });

third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Responsibilities Held ", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(": ", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase( Responsibilities_held, other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });

third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description of Work Done", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(": ", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase( Description_of_work_done, other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });

document.Add(third_table);
```